# create dynamic attachments using php

Tags: php, email

i am doing mail concepts. in this i want to send a dynamic attachments with email.
actually user gets email with attachment. this attachment will be dynamic. how to create dynamic attachment for email.i tried this. but no use. anybody help.

i have 'attachments.txt'file with content

```
User Name: <<name>>
Designid:<<designid>>
Designname:<<designname>>
Orderid:<<orderid>>
```

i was updated this file as

```
$myfile = "attachments.txt";
$fh = fopen($myfile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = str_replace("<<name>>", $fetuser[firstname], $fh);
//echo $fetuser[firstname];exit;
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = str_replace("<<designid>>",$_SESSION[designid], $fh);
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = str_replace("<<designname>>", $fetch_designname[designtype], $fh);
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = str_replace("<<orderno>>", $ordno, $fh);
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

finally i was added attachment in mail like this `$mail->AddAttachment("$myfile");`

but this is not working properly. anybody help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can pass a file handler to `str_replace` like that. Read in the contents first, replace your placeholders, and then write the file again. Also, if you write this to the same file containing your template, it will no longer be a template the second time you want to send an email, but I'm sure you thought of something for that :)

EDIT:

So, you can do someting like this:

```
$text = file_get_contents($templateFile);

// perhaps some error handling here

$text = str_replace(array('<<name>>', '<<designid>>', '<<designname>>', '<<orderid>>'),
                    array($fetuser[firstname], $_SESSION[designid], $fetch_designname[designtype], $ordno),
                    $text);

file_put_contents($attachmentFile, $text);
```

Comment: yes. you are right. it will no longer be a template . but i want it will be like a template. how can?

Comment: Well, just use one file as the template and only read from it, and use another file (or files) as your attachment. Also, as @symcbean is suggesting, it may be possible to add attachments without writing them to disk first, which would be even better. You'd have to find out how to do it, though. Anyway, the key here is not to write to your template file.

Comment: yes i copy function copied a file into newfile. modified this newfile. after mail sent deleting this new file. thanks to both.

Comment: Do you mean you would like to create a pdf file this way? If so, I suggest you open a pdf file with a text editor :) Anyway, there are several free php pdf classes online. Here's one: http://www.fpdf.org/.

Comment: you mean convert modified textfile as pdf file?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you bothering to write the file back to disk? It's not necessary.

> $mail->AddAttachment("$myfile");

Can you give us a clue what $mail is instantiated from?

> but this is not working properly

That's a meaningless statement. Please provide error messages or details of how the results differ from what you were expecting.